# Using MPI_Reduce in C for Multiple Operations

Tags: c, max, mpi, min

I am working on an MPI program to compute the average, min, and max of a large data array. Each process computes the local min/max/avg based on their chunk of the array. At the end of the program, I call MPI_Reduce 3 times in a row (once with MPI_MIN, once with MPI_MAX, and once with MPI_SUM) [code below]. Intuitively, this seems like a bottleneck, but I am not sure I understand what I should do instead.

Should I instead put the 3 values into an array and send this data to the root process, then perform the operations on it manually? Or should I pass an array of 3 values and then write my own reduction function?

```
    // Find Max in our local buffer
    for(i=0;i<array_size;i++){

            sum += tempDataBuffer[i];

            if(local_max < tempDataBuffer[i]){
                    local_max = tempDataBuffer[i];
            }else if(local_min > tempDataBuffer[i]){
                    local_min = tempDataBuffer[i];
            }

    }

    int local_avg = sum/i;

    int global_max, global_min, global_avg;

    MPI_Reduce(&local_max, &global_max, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MAX, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&local_min, &global_min, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Reduce(&local_avg, &global_avg, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    global_avg = global_avg/nprocs;
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Please comment if you down vote so I can learn how to ask my question more properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely won't make a lot of difference in terms of performance. Think about what you'd have to do if you decided to do things on one rank instead of via MPI collectives.

First, you'd have to do an `MPI_GATHER` to get all of the data on a single process. You'd have to make sure to allocate enough memory for all of the data from all of the processes, and you'd have to perform the calculation. Finally, you'd have to send it back out to everyone with an `MPI_BCAST`.

In the end, you'd save yourself one `MPI_REDUCE`, but you'd instead gain more memory allocation and computation. It might be slightly faster to get rid of one collective operation, but probably not significantly so, and the tradeoffs as you get to larger and larger scales becomes even less clear as reduction operations are highly optimized in most MPI applications.

Comment: thank you! this was exactly the kind of thorough answer I was hoping for (to help my own understanding).